# Quick copy and paste over Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, copy-paste

Can I make quick copy & pastes between devices over Bluetooth?

I know how to move files between devices but have always felt that a clipboard-like approach would be a great feature.

Examples:

- I'd like to copy a URL from my browser here and paste it in the address bar of Opera Mini running on my mobile phone before logging out from my computer.
- Copy a contact from my address book  on my phone and paste it into the email client on my laptop.

How do I get this functionality working over Bluetooth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to install a VNC server on the mobile phone (such as [MobileVNC](http://www.pocketvnc.com/blog/?page_id=7), [mVNC](http://www.m-shell.net/products/mvnc.aspx) or [Veency](http://lifehacker.com/5066254/veency-offers-remote-control-of-your-jailbroken-iphone)). Then you CopyNPaste your stuff via a VNC-Viewer.

Comment: But aren't these things heavy?

Comment: define "heavy".

Comment: I could ask you to define "define" and we'd be even. I won't.

Comment: @Agnel Kurian: my mobile phone can now do easily things you would need a normal pc some years ago. thus, define 'heavy'.  if you want to go the btooth-only route: well, then you have to start the an app which gets its stuff from the btooth adapter .. guesses where you want it to have and then "does the right thing" .. can't imagine an app which does that.

Answer (score 5):

- Copy and paste to QR code generator.
- Scan code from screen

I just found that. My life is about to take a big turn.